# Getting specific item from json response without any serilization in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter

I am using blogger api and in my app I just want to get the "content" value nothing more nothing less. How can I do that without serilizations?

This is the json response:

```
{
  "kind": "blogger#postList",
  "items": [
    {
      "content": {
          "name": "Tesula Parajuli",
          "address":"Biratnagar",
          "type": "Kabita",
          "text":"Ajai ma rati\\nk ssss sapana ma\\nmai mari gayeko\\nmai mari gayeko.",
          "fb_link":"https://www.facebook.com/Sulav2059",
          "photo":"https://scontent.fktm1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c17.0.240.240a/p240x240/133496545_687004428585872_4614063345221687073_o.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=2&_nc_sid=7206a8&_nc_ohc=o-ZPIXOH3B0AX8RT6fj&_nc_ht=scontent.fktm1-1.fna&tp=27&oh=c90b454649168f6d0b91454d5c7155b9&oe=60130954",
      },
      "etag": "\"dGltZXN0YW1wOiAxNjA5NTcyNzExMjA1Cm9mZnNldDogLTI4ODAwMDAwCg\""
    },
    {
      "content": {
          "name":"Sulav Parajuli",
          "address":"Biratnagar",
          "type": "Kabita",
          "text":"Ajai ma rati\\nk dekhe sapana ma\\nmai mari gayeko\\nmai mari gayeko.",
          "fb_link":"https://www.facebook.com/Sulav2059\",\n\"photo\":\"https://scontent.fktm1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c17.0.240.240a/p240x240/133496545_687004428585872_4614063345221687073_o.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=2&_nc_sid=7206a8&_nc_ohc=o-ZPIXOH3B0AX8RT6fj&_nc_ht=scontent.fktm1-1.fna&tp=27&oh=c90b454649168f6d0b91454d5c7155b9&oe=60130954",
      },
      "etag": "\"dGltZXN0YW1wOiAxNjA5NTcyNjgxOTY2Cm9mZnNldDogLTI4ODAwMDAwCg\""
    }
  ],
  "etag": "\"MjAyMS0wMS0wMlQwNzozMTo1MS4yMDVa\""
}
```

The code for getting data:

```
Future<http.Response> readDataFromDb() async {
  var url = 'url-text';


  return http.get(
    url,
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  );
}
```

And I am doing this on initState:

```
 readDataFromDb().then((value){
      setState(() {
        values = value.body;
      });
    });
```

Now what  I want is list of the contents saved in something like List which I can  iterate through to create listview.

Comment: But there are multiple `content` fields in your response. You want to iterate them or just need to get the first one ?

Comment: itreate over them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. But next time, make some efforts

```
class _SamplePageState extends State<SamplePage> {
  List contents;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialize your variable
    contents = [];

    initData();
  }

  void initData() {
    readDataFromDb().then((response) {
      var res = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (mounted) setState(() {
        for (var item in res["items"]) contents.add(item["content"]);
      });
    }).catchError((_) {});
  }

  Future<http.Response> readDataFromDb() async {
    var url = 'url-text';

    return await http.get(url, headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: contents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("Name : " + contents[index]["name"]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i do so as the response I am getting is a String response?

Comment: please see my question edit and help me i am totally beginner

Comment: "I know I am dumb"
pls help me your code at  
```for (var item in res["items"]) contents.add(item["content"]);```
is giving me the another error:
"type string is not a subtype of type int of index"

Comment: Are you sure the provided json is the result you get over your API call ?

Comment: yes i am sure 100% but when I json decode the item again it works!